# Elasticsearch: find documents where source is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve the documents where the source is empty. I tried the following query but am unable to get expected results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "_source"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In what case can such a thing happen?

Comment: @Val we are bulk indexing. The legacy code returns an empty hash when any error occurs while preparing the JSON data. Hence, the empty source.

Comment: Why not checking in your legacy code that the hash is empty and not index it if that's the case?

Comment: @Val code has been fixed. but we need to reindex the missing documents.

Comment: Gotcha! is there a field that all your documents should contain? If that's the case you can check the existence of that field instead of `_source`.